# Variant of Sliding Ladder Related Rates Problem

Tags: related-rates

We all know the related rates problem of a ladder sliding off a wall. [image]

In this we are told how fast the bottom or top is sliding and then asked to find how fast the other end of the ladder is moving at. My question is fairly similar.

A ladder of length $2l$ is sliding off of a wall. The bottom moves at a velocity $v$. How fast will the *middle* of the ladder (which is located a distance $l$ from the ends of the ladder) be sliding when the angle between the rod, wall, and floor is $\alpha = 45^{\circ}$?

Comment: The middle of the ladder is moving in a curve in the plane, its x and y coordinates are functions of t. What are you asking about? dx/dt or dy/dt or the rate of change of arc length. ds/dt?

Comment: @P.Lawrence It seems to me that the answer to "How fast is it moving," is $ds/dt$.

Comment: You can give either answer. Though I think related rates would go better with the former option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the bottom of the ladder have position $(x(t),0)$.

Let the top of the ladder have position $(0,y(t))$.

We know that $x^2+y^2=4l^2$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ gives $2x \frac {dx}{dt}+2y \frac {dy}{dt}=0$.

We know that $\frac {dx}{dt}=v$, so $2xv+2y \frac {dy}{dt}=0  \Rightarrow \frac {dy}{dt}=-\frac {vx}y$.

The midpoint has position $(x_m,y_m)=(\frac x2, \frac y2)$

$\frac {dx_m}{dt}=\frac 12 \frac {dx}{dt}=\frac v2$

$\frac {dy_m}{dt}=\frac 12 \frac {dy}{dt}=\frac {vx}{2y}$

Speed is given by $\sqrt{\left(\frac {dx_m}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac {dy_m}{dt}\right)^2}$

Speed is $\sqrt{\frac {v^2}{4}+\frac {v^2x^2}{4y^2}}=\sqrt{\frac {v^2y^2+v^2x^2}{4y^2}}=\sqrt{\frac {v^2(y^2+x^2)}{4y^2}}=\sqrt{\frac {v^24l^2}{4y^2}}=\frac {vl}{y}$

When $\alpha = 45^\circ$, $x=y=l\sqrt2$

So speed of midpoint is $\frac v{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 1):

Going with saulspatz's interpretation, let the top of the ladder be at $(0,y_1)$ and the bottom at $(x_2,0)$ at time $t.$ Then the middle of the ladder is at $$(x,y)=(\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{y_1}{2})$$.$$\dot s=\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2}$$ 
$$=\sqrt{(\frac {\dot x_2}{2})^2+(\frac {\dot y_1}{2})^2}$$
$$\frac {1}{2}\sqrt{\dot x_2^2+\dot y_1^2}$$ Since $\dot {x_2}$ is how fast the bottom of the ladder is sliding along the floor and $\dot{y_1}$ is how fast the top of the ladder is sliding down the wall, you should be able to take it from there.